# FusedLocationService not aquiring GPS signal in Android

Tags: android, location

I'm using the new FusedLocationService, but, despite I'm getting latitude and longitude while being indoors, I don't see GPS signal being aquired (small gps point in the notifications bar not appearing).

I'm using the example from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html) adapted to location service

What I don't understand is why GPS signal is not being searched for despite GPS is enabled (but I'm getting coordinates, I guess I getting those from wifi or cell id)

In my Application class  I create a Service (this is a ServicesManager, which in turn creates another service (to retrieve locations). I'm sending as context to LocationClient the ServicesManager as it is a context (because it's a Service).

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

**UPDATE**
If I turn off the Use Wireless Network option in location services on the phone while GPS is enabled I don't get locations at all. So something is happening with the FusedLocationService and the GPS.

I'll add code so it can be better understood

In **Application** class I'm using the LocalService example from: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

```
private ServicesManager mBoundService;
    private boolean mIsBound;

    private ServiceConnection mConnectionToServicesManager = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            mBoundService = ((ServicesManager.LocalBinder)service).getService();

    servicesManager = mBoundService;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mBoundService = null;
        }
    };

    void doBindServiceManagerService() {
        bindService(new Intent(this, ServicesManager.class), mConnectionToServicesManager, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            unbindService(mConnectionToServicesManager);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }
```

Then **ServicesManager** extends Service and in the constructor I'm writing this:

```
fusedLocationService = new FusedLocationService(this);
```

Then I call to:

```
fusedLocationService.startListeningLocationUpdates(this);
```

This is the implementation of **startListeningLocationUpdates** in **FusedLocationService** class

```
public boolean startListeningLocationUpdates(Context context) {
    if (!GdpTesisApplication.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable) {
        return false;
    }

    mDetectionRequester.requestUpdates();
    FusedLocationService.IsServiceRunning  = true;
    return true;
}
```

And requestUpdates() tries to connecto to GooglePlayServices

```
private void requestConnection() {
    getFusedLocationClient().connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    continueRequestLocationUpdates();
}

private void continueRequestLocationUpdates() {
    locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationrequest.setInterval(LocationUtils.DETECTION_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS);

    getFusedLocationClient().requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, createRequestPendingIntent());
}

private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {
    if (null != getRequestPendingIntent()) {
        return mFusedLocationPendingIntent;
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FusedLocationIntentService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        setRequestPendingIntent(pendingIntent);
        return pendingIntent;
    }
}
```

Finally I have an IntentService which onHandleIntent extracts the location and shows it with:

```
Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
```

I don't know why GPS is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setPriority%28int%29

You didn't set a priority for your LocationRequest. Try with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY.